# What are the most modern browsers available on Mac OS 10.4

Tags: web-browsing, macos

I have two old Mac Minis both running OS X 10.4 Tiger.

One is a G4 so I'm using TenFourFox for PowerPC.

The other has an Intel processor and I'm having some trouble with Opera 10.62.

(The point is I want to use trello.com and old browsers like FireFox 3 or standard Safari from the 10.4 OS won't work).

What other options am I missing?

Comment: Can't you upgrade to Leopard? I am typing this from a PPC G5 tower that's running Leopard.

Comment: Thanks @daviesgeek I guess I'll try to upgrade the Intel Mini, the G4 I'm not sure it would run 10.5.

Comment: Which G4 is it? Look up your serial # [here](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/) and lemme know which one you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to resurrect this thread, but the answer has changed since last year. I'm posting this mainly for the benefit of people who will find this thread by googling "modern web browser for tiger". If you still use this computer, I would have to recommend you upgrade from Camino to [Omniweb](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniweb/).

Camino stopped updating their browser a few months ago and has no plans to continue support. Omniweb on the other hand is still being updated and supported and still runs on Tiger. Here is Omniweb running Trello.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend downloading [Camino](http://caminobrowser.org/). Camino is modern enough that it loads [Trello:](http://trello.com)

[image: Trello on Camino]
[image: Camino and Google]

It's based on the Mozilla project, so the GUI is very similar to early versions of Firefox:
[image: Camino bar]